Interpolating Reservoir Data over Mesh File
I have a mesh file that has a homogeneous Vp, Vs, and rho_sat (pressure wave velocity, shear wave velocity, and density). I also have a reservoir file that has a depth of 0 to 250 and has the varying Vp, Vs, and rho_sat values. I have adjusted the reservoir file so that it ranges from 820 to 1070, and therefore matches the depth in the mesh file. What I am currently trying to do is find every point within the mesh file that is in between -820 and -1070 and interpolate the Vp, Vs, and rho_sat of the reservoir model over the mesh file for these points. I keep running into the issue that my interpolated values are all NaN, so when I try interpolating over the mesh it just leaves everything as the homogeneous value and plots a blank graph. I have included my code down below, if anyone notices  if there is something wrong with it that is creating this problem or have any tips for me, I would greatly appreciate it!
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the proc file
data = np.loadtxt('proc000000_rho_vp_vs.dat')

# Load the reservoir model
df_res = pd.read_csv('vel_HZ_Reuss_0001_ed.csv')

# Adjust reservoir model x values to match desired coordinate system
df_res['z'] = -df_res['z'] + 1070  # Shift z values to match proc file's coordinate system

# Extract x, z, Vp, Vs, density from reservoir model
x_res = df_res['x']
z_res = df_res['z']
Vp_res = df_res['Vp']
Vs_res = df_res['Vs']
rhosat_res = df_res['rho_sat']

# Check bounds of the reservoir model
print(f"Reservoir model bounds:")
print(f"x: min={x_res.min()}, max={x_res.max()}")
print(f"z: min={z_res.min()}, max={z_res.max()}")

# Create interpolators for reservoir model data
interp_Vp = scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(list(zip(x_res, z_res)), Vp_res)
interp_Vs = scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(list(zip(x_res, z_res)), Vs_res)
interp_rhosat = scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator(list(zip(x_res, z_res)), rhosat_res)

# Extract x and z values from the proc file
xvalues = data[:, 0]  # x values are in the first column
zvalues = data[:, 1]  # z values are in the second column

# Initialize output lists
xout, zout, vpout, vsout, rhosatout = [], [], [], [], []

# Initialize counters
count_if = 0
count_else = 0

#start of for loop
for q in range(1140011, 1140036): #make smaller range to check where NaN is coming from 
  X = xvalues[q]
  Z = zvalues[q]`

  if -1070 <= Z <= -920:
    X,Z = np.meshgrid(X,Z)
    Vp_int = interp_Vp(X, Z) 
    Vs_int = interp_Vs(X, Z)
    rho_int = interp_rhosat(X, Z)
    print(interp_Vp) #attempt to debug, returning NaN
    print(rho_int) #attempt to debug, returning NaN
   
    xout.append(np.float64(X))
    zout.append(np.float64(Z))
    vpout.append(np.float64(Vp_int))
    vsout.append(np.float64(Vs_int))
    rhosatout.append(np.float64(rho_int))
   
    count_if += 1  # Increment the counter for 'if' conditions

  else:
    xout.append(np.float64(X))
    zout.append(np.float64(Z))
    vpout.append(np.float64(4260)) 
    vsout.append(np.float64(2530))
    rhosatout.append(np.float64(2519.5))
   
    count_else += 1  # Increment the counter for 'else' condition   
#end of for loop

# Print the counts after the loop
print(f"{count_if} indices have met the criteria.")
print(f"{count_else} indices have not met the criteria.")

# Replace NaN values with default values - replacing all values??

for q in range(len(xout)):
  if np.isnan(vpout[q]):
    vpout[q] = 4260
    vsout[q] = 2530
    rhosatout[q] = 2519.5

filename = 'interpolated_proc_data.txt'

saveas = np.column_stack((xout, zout, rhosatout, vpout, vsout))
np.savetxt(filename, saveas)

# Convert lists to numpy arrays for plotting
xout = np.array(xout)
zout = np.array(zout)
vpout = np.array(vpout)

# Plot the interpolated Vp values
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(xout, zout, marker='o', cmap='jet')
#plt.ylim(-1070,0)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Z')
plt.show()

I have tried multiple lines of debugging. I know 400,000 indices are meeting the criteria and that the data from my csv file has been loaded in correctly and that the values are loaded in as float64 not strings. I am not sure what to try to make it so my interpolated values are not NaN.

Welcome to SO, please turn your post into [mcve] by publishing your datasets as shared links.
